# How to remove armpit stains?

Tags: cleaning, clothing, laundry

I have some white T-shirts where the armpits have stains really hard to remove. They are brown-colored stains. What's the way to remove the stains?

Comment: if you find anything that works, I'd like to know about it - as far as I'm aware, there is no way to remove that sort of staining, it develops over time, is often yellow rather than brown, is related as much to deodorants as it is to perspiration, and is indelible. Worse on white, of course, and if the clothing is close fitting under the arms, you just have to replace the clothing more often. Bleach may make the whole garment a sort of dirty yellow, depending on the fabric and dye process used.

Comment: One year, I would spray a stain remover on my shirt pits every time I put a shirt in the laundry basket. I remember that the stains developed more slowly, so I could wear my white shirts for a few more months before replacing them. However I had to spray the pits EVERY TIME I wore a light shirt.

Answer (score 1):

Just add some bleach to water and wash your shirts in that.

Comment: This is good on plain white shirts, but damaging if they have any decoration.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of methods that when applied individually or in combination (for deep-cleanse) directly onto the stains worked in our case.

- Make a thick paste of some Oxi-Clean powder and some water. Apply and leave for some time and then wash in hottest water possible.
- Spray for stain remover (Shout brand with Oxi-Clean enriched is one we used) worked.
- Use a paste of baking soda on the stains.

These work perfectly with blend type fabrics and pretty well on pure cotton fabrics.

Also frequent application is important, if the stains have been building up for a long time, it will take several applications to break it down completely.

Comment: Oxy-Clean works, I have done this a few times. Make it into a paste for really bad spot stains, or put it all in a bucket and soak - read instructions on packet.

Answer (score 1):

Mix these 3 products:

1. one part of dish-washing soap
2. two parts of hydrogen peroxide
3. a sprinkle of baking soda

   - **STEP 1** use a laundry brush to work the mixture into the stain
   - **STEP 2** let the treated shirt sit for an hour
   - **STEP 3** wash normally

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have a few T-shirts that have been dyed dark colors in the washing machine. This might hide light staining or an over-all yellowing affect from bleaching.

Relevant results when dying T-shirts:

- Some (nylon?) seam stitches didn't absorb dye and remain perfectly white.
- Silk-screen ink was generally unaffected and looks like it was applied to the color shirt.
- The amount of clothes being dyed affect how dark the resulting colors will be.

Answer (score 0):

Apply some drops of lemon juice and rinse it.

Answer (score 0):

Put the t-shirts for a few hours in a mix of water and vinegar, then wash them. I have tested this. It works

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this:

> - Presoak in vinegar and water solution
> - Mix together baking soda, salt, and hydrogen peroxide until it forms a paste.
> - Remove the shirt from the vinegar water and gently squeeze until the shirt is just damp.
> - Lay flat on a towel-covered work surface and coat the stains with the mixture.

http://www.popsugar.com/smart-living/How-Remove-Sweat-Stains-31003483

Answer (score 0):

I follow this technique:

1. Add a cup of detergent powder in half bucket of water and stir it well.
2. Turn the t-shirts inside-out and immerse them in that bucket and let them soak for about 10-15 minutes.
3. Rub the stained portion of the t-shirt with a detergent soap bar.
4. Then finally brush the stained portion with a garment brush and rinse.

This will vanish the stains and this technique works well. Hope this helps.

General tip: You can easily maintain the white color of the t-shirt or any other garment for a long period of time if you wash them seperately. Don't put the t-shirt along with all other clothes in a washing machine.

Answer (score 0):

I use GOOP hand cleaner as a laundry stain remover. It's inexpensive,  and has worked well on any type stain I've smeared it over. Let it sit for a little while (I have left it sitting for 10 minutes to 4 hours).
I find it in the automotive section at wal mart. Does clean greasy hand very well also.

Answer (score 0):

Tie-dye those shirts with multiple colours, and nobody will notice the brown.  Who needs white T-shirts anyway?